# How to use blocking Queue to process Camera feed in background?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, blockingqueue

I have been facing a problem while processing the camera feeds in android Application for 'face detection''.

**What i am trying to do:**

-I have An activity which shows continuosly the phone camera feed in a surfaceView(UI thread)

-To avoid performance headaches,I put a surfaceview on top to draw the Rectangles over the detected faces using OpenCv(This is running in a thread,say thread2)

-I am trying to pass a copy of the Direct feed image to the Thread2 so that the thread 2 can do the detection and draw on the overlay surfaceview

**Where i am now:**

-I was thinking of using a thread with a blockingqueue so that the UIthread can put the Image in to the BlockingQueue using BlockingQueue.add(..) and the Thread2 can take the image in the BlockingQ ,process it and detect faces in background

**Conditions:**
  I want the UI thread ,not to wait,so that uniterupted feed is seen on the display.It only need to put the image and then without waiting for anything else it can go and fetch next feed and process is repeated

Currently i am using a new class implementing Runnable interface which has two methods putImage(bitmap) and getImage() which puts and get images using the blockingQueue.putImage() is called by UIthread and getImage() is called by thread2

**The problem:**
  When i keep putting on the Images to the blocking Queue,the Thread2 cant access the blockingQ(Itsblocked) and since the UI thread should run uninterrupted,I cannot call wait() or sleep() in the Main thread.

Is there any way Thread2 can get this Images from Queue without blocking the MainThread???

Comment: This needs more detail to explain the problem. What does it mean "When i keep putting on the Images to the blocking Queue,the Thread2 cant access the blockingQ(Itsblocked)"? That doesn't sound right. The way the BlockingQueue works, is that Thread2 gets blocked on the `poll()` method, while waiting for something to go into the queue.  The Camera Feed Thread can put something on the queue without getting blocked. If it is getting blocked, something else is wrong. Zeller's answer below does explain that if your Camera Feed thread hits the queue limit, it blocks. Are you hitting the limit?

Comment: Yeah i am hitting the limit.I used a arrayBlockingQueue and initailised its size to 30(for holding 30 frames).The problem i faced is that the Producer hits the limit very fast.Its obvious that the rate at which camera produces the frames will be much larger than the rate at which FaceProcesser completes processing them.So if the produer produces 30fps,the consumer will be able to process less fps.So the Queue will always hit the limit right??

Comment: Yes.  This differential between how fast the camera streams, and how fast the processing thread processes will give you an idea of how much space you need to save.  Perhaps an idea to help smooth this out, is to make your other thread save to storage instead of processing, and then create a third thread to read from storage and do the Face Processing.  The advantage to this is that saving to storage will probably be much faster than processing, so the Camera Feed Thread won't be delayed as much by the Storage thread. And you may not need any synch. between Storage and Process threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a typical producer-consumer problem. Your producer should be the main thread. And the consumer is the one that detects the faces. It is the consumer that will have to run in a different thread. There is no need for a separate thread that handles the queue, it can be anywhere where it is accessible for the producer and the consumer.

 This way there shouldn't be any blocking unless your queue is bounded. A default [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) is practically unbounded.

 To access ready products without blocking you could do the following: Declare an other queue that will hold the result of the done tasks. The face processor will be it's producer and the main thread will be the consumer. Let the processor fill it as it goes, and the main thread periodically check it for ready products. If it finds that the result queue is not empty, you can notify the user or do whatever you want.

Comment: Thats one pretty good solution zeller but the point is that for such a mobile application,using an unbounded queue is not practical right??The memory usage will increase and the app will ultimately crash.But anyways I will try out like what you said and get back to you soon..Thanks Zeller

Comment: @KP_K Think about how much memory you need to store a task in the queue.  Most likely, much less then processing an element. If it is still a concern, then you must say stop at some point and don't process the faces any longer. You can then save somehow how much of the work is queued, then continue when the resources are freed.

Comment: Hey... I followed your idea and my program worked.But i did it using a Bounded Queue(ArrayBQ) and i managed the Memory as below:
I first maintained a small sized Queue and then tried to add the Images from the producer thread.The producer thread also checks whether the Queue is full.If full it delets the last item(In FIFO).The consumer thread uses the take() function to wait and then retrieves the last Image ,Process it and display the results.

Thanks a lot for clarifying the concept of producer consumer concept :)

Comment: You're welcome. Though, are you sure that deleting items is ok? If yes in your application, then fine, but otherwise work out something to not loose tasks.

Comment: People coming across this may find this answer helpful also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963773/android-asynctask-to-process-live-video-frames