# Android Asynctask to process live video frames

Tags: android, image-processing, android-asynctask

I am using OpenCV to attempt to do some live video processing.  Since the processing is fairly heavy, it delays the output frames significantly, making the live stream look choppy.

I'd like to offload some of the processing into an AsyncTask.  I've tried it and it actually makes the video much smoother.  However, it ends up starting a large amount of Tasks at once, and then they will slowly start returning with some results.

Is there any way to slow this down, and wait for a result, either by using Synchronize statements, or some other method?

On each camera frame, I start one of these tasks.  DoImgProcessing does the long processing and returns a string result.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Mat, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Mat... params) {
        Mat inputFrame = params[0];
        cropToCenter(inputFrame);
        return doImgProcessing(inputFrame);
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "on post execute: "+result);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "on pre execute");
    }
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);//this will be used for the live stream
    LongOperation op = new LongOperation();
    op.execute(inputFrame);
    return mRgba;
}
```

Comment: I'd use a single thread with a blockingqueue to put frames in.

Comment: I've never written one of these, Id be happy to accept your answer if you could give alittle sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like that :

```
// Example value for a timeout.
private static final long TIMEOUT = 1000L;

private BlockingQueue<Mat> frames = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Mat>();

Thread worker = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Mat inputFrame = frames.poll(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (inputFrame == null) {
                // timeout. Also, with a try {} catch block poll can be interrupted via Thread.interrupt() so not to wait for the timeout.
                continue;
            }
            cropToCenter(inputFrame);
            String result = doImgProcessing(inputFrame);
        }
    }
};
worker.start();

public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);//this will be used for the live stream
    frames.put(inputFrame);
    return mRgba;
}
```

The onCameraFrame puts the frame on the Queue, the worker Thread polls from the Queue.

This decorelate the reception and the treatment of the frame. You can monitor the growth of the Queue using `frames.size()`.

This is a typical producer-consumer example.

Comment: Awesome example.  Two questions though, first, this boolean running variable, should that theoretically be running throughout the entire activity?  Also, do you suggest that when adding the frames to the queue, I say something like, if(frames.size() < 4){frames.put(inputFrame);} ??

Comment: Typically, you'll have to decide for a stop condition. `running = false` is a quick and simple way of handling it, but it means you'd drop the rest of the queue (which may or may not be the expected behaviour).

Comment: As for the queue size, you can use a fixed capacity queue (add limit in constructor), and use `offer(inputFrame)`, which will try to put the object, and return false if there is no room available. That means you may drop frames, but you'll have something close to real-time treatment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on each frame, it sounds like you need a thread instead.  An AsyncTask is for when you want to do a one-off activity on another thread.  Here you want to do it repeatedly.  Just create a thread, and when it finishes a frame have it post a message to a handler to run the post step on the UI thread.  It can wait on a semaphore at the top of its loop for the next frame to be ready.

Comment: I could see how that could work.  But isn't an AsyncTask really just a thread anyway?

Comment: Do you think there is an advantage to letting the system start more than one frame processing at a time?

Comment: It runs on a thread, but the thread exits.  If you're doing something contantly, that's actually counter to what you want.  As for more than 1-  actually getting more than 1 async task at a time is difficult, it requires special code on some android versions.  And it would only be useful if the OS is smart rnough to run them on different cores, which I doubt it is.