# How to play a sound on android with a delay?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm doing a small school project of object detection by color. When the object arrives in the center of the screen, it must have a sound. So the sound does not stay uninterrupted, I tried to put a delay on it. But every time the application arrives at the point of playing the sound, it closes. I already researched here and in other forums and the solutions presented did not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{

    static {
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d("TAG", "OpenCV not loaded");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "OpenCV loaded");
        }
    }

    public void voltatela(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Mat imgHVS, imgThresholded;
    Scalar sc1, sc2;
    JavaCameraView cameraView;
    int largura, altura;

    public void Verde(View v) {
        sc1 = new Scalar(45, 20, 10);
        sc2 = new Scalar(75, 255, 255);
        irTelaCamera();
    }

    public void Azul(View v) {
        sc1 = new Scalar(80, 50, 50);
        sc2 = new Scalar(100, 255, 255);
        irTelaCamera();
    }

    public void Vermelho(View v) {
        sc1 = new Scalar(110, 100, 50);
        sc2 = new Scalar(130, 255, 255);
        irTelaCamera();
    }

    public void irTelaCamera(){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.telacamera);
        cameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.cameraview);
        cameraView.setCameraIndex(0); //0 para traseira e 1 para dianteira
        cameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        cameraView.enableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        imgHVS = new Mat(width,height, CvType.CV_16UC4);
        imgThresholded = new Mat(width,height, CvType.CV_16UC4);
        largura = width;
        altura = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Point centrotela = new Point((largura*0.5),(altura*0.5));
        final MediaPlayer som = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bip);
        Imgproc.medianBlur(imgHVS,imgHVS,1);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.rgba(), imgHVS,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Core.inRange(imgHVS, sc1, sc2, imgThresholded);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, new Size(3, 3), 1, 1);
        Mat circles = new Mat();
        double dp = 1.2d;
        int minRadius = 20;
        int maxRadius = 0;
        double param1 = 100, param2 = 20;
        int desvio = (int) (minRadius*0.5);
        Imgproc.HoughCircles(imgThresholded, circles, Imgproc.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, imgThresholded.rows()/4, 100, 20, minRadius, maxRadius);
        int numCircles = (circles.rows() == 0) ? 0 : circles.cols();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCircles; i++) {
            double[] circleCoordinates = circles.get(0, i);
            int x = (int) circleCoordinates[0], y = (int) circleCoordinates[1];
            Point center = new Point(x, y);
            int radius = (int) circleCoordinates[2];
            if((((center.x-desvio) <= centrotela.x) && ((center.x+desvio) >= centrotela.x))) {
                if ((((center.y-desvio) <= centrotela.y) && ((center.y+desvio) >= centrotela.y))) {
                    som.start();
                    Imgproc.circle(imgThresholded, center, radius, new Scalar(100, 255, 255), 4);

                    // Play sound after 2 sec delay
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            som.stop();
                        }
                    }, 2000);
            }}
        }
        Imgproc.circle(imgThresholded,centrotela,50, new Scalar(100,255,255),7);
        Imgproc.circle(imgThresholded,centrotela,25, new Scalar(100,255,255),4);
        Imgproc.circle(imgThresholded,centrotela,5, new Scalar(100,255,255),-1);
        return imgThresholded;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message when the app crashed?

Comment: Provide the error log.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write sop.start(); instead of sop.stop() inside the handler;

Comment: This would not help sound being play too many times because onCameraFrame will be call many times per sec.

Comment: in the above question , He need to start the audio after 2 seconds and inside the handler its written to stop the mediaplayer

Comment: I know. You are right, but I don't think that solve the crash. Still waiting for Error message though.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried playing the sound in a different thread ([AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14963773/267693)). You would have to keep track if you have already spawned a task though, otherwise, you will end up creating too many threads playing the same sound.